# .htaccess rewrite URL to unminified version of file (if it exists) based on query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to serve the unminified version of any file with `nomin` in its URL.

For example, if I request:

```
http://localhost/foo/bar.min.js?nomin
```

I should receive the file:

```
http://localhost/foo/bar.js
```

However, I want that to happen only if the file exists.

This is what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} nomin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.min(\..*)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1$2 -f
RewriteRule (.*)\.min(\..*) $1$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

However, it doesn't work. If I remove the line where I check if the file exists:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1$2 -f
```

It starts working, but may point to non-existent files.

I tried:

- Removing the slash `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$1$2 -f`.
- Using `REQUEST_URI` like that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}/$1$2 -f` (with and without slash), even though it doesn't make much sense.
- Matching the whole thing and only checking the parts excluding ".min"

  ```
  RewriteCond $0 (.*)\.min(\..*)
  RewriteCond $1$2 -f
  ```

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

*Side question:* Is there a way to change my `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` such that I don't have to write `(.*)\.min(\..*)` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^nomin$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\.min(\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%2 -f
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [L,NC]
```

Use `%1`, `%2` instead of `$1`, `$2` for values being captured from `RewriteCond`

Comment: It doesn't work. On your second line, you use `$1` and `$2`. Aren't they unset? That's kind of the reason I had that `REQUEST_URI` part - to set those two variables. Also, I need it to work in any directory/subdirectory.

Comment: No they are not unset because `$1` and `$2` are set in the `RewriteRule` itself.

Comment: Doesn't `.htaccess` alter requests for any file in the directory it is in, or any subdirectory?

Comment: Your edited solution worked. Could you explain what was my problem? How exactly did you fix it?

Comment: as I wrote in answer, `Use %1, %2 instead of $1, $2 for values being captured from RewriteCond`.  Also another important point about `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` is that it always works on complete URI instead of just a per directory relative as the case with `RewriteRule`.